# Comparing SQL table to $_SESSION['user'] and printing current user info

Tags: php, sqlite

First off I'm very new to coding in general. I have an sql-database with table:

```
CREATE TABLE "users" (
    `id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    `name`  VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `username`      VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `email` VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `password`      VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `biography`     VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    `img`   VARCHAR
);
```

I wish to compare `users['id']` to `$_SESSION['user']` and print out all information for current user in a profile page. As of right now my code is:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id';
$statement = $pdo->query($query);

if (!$statement) {
die(var_dump($pdo->errorInfo()));
}


$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($rows as $row) {
}
```

What I'm lacking is where I compare the `users['id']` to `$_SESSION['user']` and I'm unsure how to specifically code for that.
Any suggestions?

Comment: `<?php
session_start();
$query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(array(':id' => $user['id'])); // change variable accordingly what you have
$rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($rows['id']  == $_SESSION['user']) {
 //do stuff
}`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id');
$sth->bindParam(':id', $_SESSION['user']);
$sth->execute();
```

and then iterate the results.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of things that seem to be undone.

1. Your sql query seems to be incomplete.

   `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$user_id'`
2. You are not initializing PDO object.

   `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_db;charset=utf8mb4', 'db_username', 'db_password');`

Complete code snippet :

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8mb4', 'db_user', 'db_pass');

    $user_id=1;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM engineers WHERE id='$user_id'";
    $statement = $pdo->query($query);

    if (!$statement) {
    die(var_dump($pdo->errorInfo()));
    }

    $rows = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo $row['name'];
        echo $row['username'];
        echo $row['biography'];
    }
?>
```

On the other hand use `$_SESSION['user_id']=$id` to set the session.